# Bluetooth always off - ASUS ROG Strix G15

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 22.04, asus

I recently acquired an ASUS ROG Strix G15 and installed ubuntu 22.04 on dual boot. Almost everything was good as always, but I ran into an issue with my bluetooth adapter. When I go into the bluetooth tab in settings pannel, I get the following:

[Adapter always off and won't turn on when I click the switch button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISucU.png)

I have tried [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608116/bluetooth-wont-turn-on-on-ubuntu-20-04) and also enabling the bluetooth service, but no success. This is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[    2.549887] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.549923] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.549925] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.549934] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.549937] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.549942] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.149493] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.149496] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.149500] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
joao@joao-ROG-Strix:~$
```

The output of `sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also bluetoothctl tells me that there is no default controller available.

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Is there any further troubleshooting that I should run?